# Change More product images on color swatch select

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product, swatches, color-swatches

I have set color swatches for configurable products and the main product image has been changed successfully by clicking on color swatch, but not the more images associated with that product.

How is that possible to do that on product view page?

**More Detail**
Change More View Images of associative product by clicking on color - I am using **magento enterprise** edition not community.

[image] swatch

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, could you go into a bit more details, join screenshots ...?

Comment: A javascript soltion http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/46969/7773

Comment: more detail added

Comment: (note that the swatches feature is the same in CE and EE)